# What would be the range safety for vertically landing over land rockets?

Tags: launch, rockets, falcon-9, range-safety, vtvl

sideFrom the [Wikipedia article on range safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_safety#Launch_corridor):

> Rockets are usually launched into a space above the launch range
>   called the launch corridor. If rocket engines fail while the rocket
>   flies inside the corridor, the rocket falls in an uninhabited area.
>   Engine failure outside the launch corridor may cause the rocket to
>   fall on people or property. Therefore, if the rocket is about to exit
>   the launch corridor, the RSO will terminate powered flight to ensure
>   that no debris falls outside the launch corridor.

The launch corridor or hazard zone is usually a corridor in the direction of launch. What will be the shape of hazard zone for a rocket flying back?

[image: Flight Corridor for Guided Suborbital Vehicle]

Flight Corridor for Guided Suborbital Vehicle

[image]
Keep Out Areas SpaceX requests for each launch.
Eventually, the red zone will cover one of the most  dense populated areas in US if Falcon 9 try landing on 'Landing Site 1'.

Comment: Didn't get it quite right, tried again. Could you add a link to the source of the image?

Comment: Credit to Reddit user darga89 for creating the launch map.

Comment: the image is from reddit.com/r/spacex  <https://i.imgur.com/M9SgxuO.png>